# How to post an Object in JAX-RS

Tags: post, jax-rs

I had code like this:

**Service class**

```
@POST
@Path("/updateProduct.htm")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String updateProduct(ProductRow productRow) {
    // ...
}
```

**Client class**

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(getBaseUrl() + "/inventory/updateProduct.htm").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
client.post(productRow);
```

**ProductRow class**

```
public class ProductRow {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // getter and setter methods
    //...
}
```

But it is throwing `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: .No message body writer has been found for class : class com.myfashions.ui.model.ProductRow, ContentType : application/xml..`          Any idea on how to do this? What are the changes need to be done to ProductRow class?

Comment: 1. Please include the details of the exception. 2. You don't include a `ProductRow` in your POST. 3. I don't see a method with `@GET` that can server `client.get(String.class)`.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add annotation `@XmlRootElement` above `ProductRow` class